# What do the symbols in the map mean in Antichamber?

Tags: antichamber

What does the spinning cross and the blinking circle on the map mean?
I guess one is your goal, what is the other one?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The spinning cross shows the room where you last entered the map. The blinking circle shows the room where you were last located when you pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The grey lines and squares show the path you took since you last entered the map.

For completeness, a large square indicates a room where you have not found all the exits, a small square indicates a room where you have found all the exits, an arrow indicates an exit (apparently only in one direction) to another part of the map, and a circle on an exit indicates a dead end.

[image: Map with legend]

As an addendum: It appears that the untaken exit symbol can also indicate untaken *entrances* (remember that in a non-Euclidean game like this, there *is* a distinction).

Comment: +1 though, this answer could really benefit from some pictures

Comment: After finishing the game, there is still a large square at "the end", is there more then 1 exits here?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the final exit from that room is just the exit to the final area, which never shows up on the map.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I added a picture.

Comment: There are, apparently, other symbols, according to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174218/what-do-these-four-symbols-on-antichambers-map-mean).  Do you think you might be able to expand this answer a bit?

Comment: I'll take a look. Though finding that information will probably require replaying the game, so I'd be grateful if anyone else gives it in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

I have few things to add to murgatroid99 [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103773/73130). Some elements are temporary, they appear when you play and then disappear at some point of playthrough.

See the picture:
[image]

3. You can have small square with untaken paths (blue). This means untaken entries. You can't take this paths from this position, but you can entry the position by this paths.
4. You can have intersection without any square (yellow). That means that you can choose different path at that point, but you can't teleport there directly using map. When you take other paths you will get a square and will be able to teleport.
5. You can have big square with not untaken exits shown (red). I had it on OSX and this looks like a bug, which is fixed after reboot.
6. You can have black path, even though you followed it (green). This also is fixed after reboot.

For comparison, this is the map after I have done all these things:
[image]