# Determine which rooms are unsolved in Antichamber

Tags: antichamber

I have the final gun (I think... red one) and a message at the exit to tie up loose ends. Is there a way, without spoiling everything or checking off a FAQ list, to determine which rooms remain unsolved or undiscovered?

Comment: I know there was one back in beta, which also let you jump to different completed rooms... I haven't played the full release yet, but there may still be an artifact of that somewhere.

Comment: Though this question isn't strictly a duplicate, the answer does answer your question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103773/13194

Comment: @Tacroy The problem with this answer is that it spoils the discovery of the map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An unfinished room appears on the map as a **large** square from which an **unfinished path** starts. Warning: an arrow does not indicate an unfinished path but a jump.